# three.js not displaying all meshes

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, 3dsmax

weird issues with 3d max 2013 obj to three.js 59 rev, in my 3d max scene i have 5 objects , cubes ...Then when i import into three.js scene i now only have 3 cubes. also there pivot point shares to the middle of all objects:

```
       var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
       loader.load( 'models/cubes.obj') ;
       loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {

       object = event.content;
       for(k in object.children){

        group.add(object.children[k]); // console said there 5 objects

        }

      });

       scene.add(group);
```

Any idea?

If i was to :

```
     group.add(object); // i will see my five cubes or 
     scene.add(object) //but then i cant access the children at all
```

Its very strange.

Comment: can't you just add the whole object with its children to the scene?
with scene.add(object); So you keep all the info from the OBJ-file instead of creating a new scene hierarchy with your group object?

Comment: i can but the same issue occurs, its weird if i just have add(object) everything shows but i cant access the children...

Comment: Why are you using an old version of the library?

Comment: i have just jumped back into webgl so i was set up from a while ago, but that is my next move, to update for now....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue is:

```
    var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();  //should be using OBJLoader
```

The other issue was the pivot point, from what i have read up around the net that the obj format has a known issue with its pivot, centre of object varies depending on the parent.
for example:

If you have three meshes cubes equal as each other, spaced out however. The pivot point of each object is not its center of its self but the centre of all the objects together.

After putting each object in its own 3d Container, this still does not solve the issue.